# Android studio error ndk then import telegram source code

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk

hello i have this error  i use source drklo 
https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

please help :(

External Native Build Issues
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
Error while executing process F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:D:\WorkSpace\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that D:/WorkSpace/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_x86.a exists  or that its path is correct
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
F:\sdk\ndk-bundle\build\core\prebuilt-library.mk
Error:(44, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)**  Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0)  **Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File
Error:(44, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Open File

Comment: Please reformat your error log, and try to be more specific in your question. If your question quality is good, you will have more probabilities to get a good answer. check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should download submodules for this project, i.e.

1. git clone https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git
2. git submodule update --init